# OpenCV Camera UDP socket stream

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, camera

I'm trying to code a client that captures raw Frames from the camera and sends these frames to the server over an udp socket.

Here is the Code from my Client:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0
if (!cap.isOpened()){
    puts("Cannot open the video cam");
    return -1;
}

double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video
cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

while (TRUE){
    cv::Mat frame;

    bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video
    if (!bSuccess){
        puts("Cannot read a frame from video stream");
        break;
    }

    frame = (frame.reshape(0, 1)); // to make it continuous
    int  imgSize = frame.total()*frame.elemSize();

    if (send(s, (const char*)frame.data, imgSize, 0) < 0){
        printf("Send failed %d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

}
```

}

Here is the server:

```
DWORD bytes = 0, imgSize = 0;
while (TRUE){

    recv(new_socket, (char*)buffer, 5999, 0);
    cv::Mat  img = cv::Mat::zeros(690, 690, CV_8UC3);
    imgSize = img.total()*img.elemSize();
    //Receive data here
    for (int i = 0; i < imgSize; i += bytes) {
        if ((bytes = recv(new_socket, (char*)sockData + i, imgSize - i, 0)) == -1) {
            puts("recv failed");
            break;
        }
    }

    // Assign pixel value to img
    int ptr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
                    // following line crashes with Access violation
            img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b(sockData[ptr + 0], sockData[ptr + 1], sockData[ptr + 2]);               ptr = ptr + 3;
        }
    }

    cv::imwrite("prova.jpg", img);
    cv::namedWindow("Server", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  //Create a Window for display
    cv::imshow("Server", img);
}
```

Using this code, I get an Access Violation on the server.
What am i doing wrong?

Can someone provide an working example?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Idk why but R_Kapp removed my question ???????